# Read data from json file and set to combobox items

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net

I have this json file below. I have downloaded it. I would like to fill a combobox with data from this json file. How can I do this in a win form application (c#)?

In my combobox I would like to show the playername as text and the resourceId as value.

https://fifa15.content.easports.com/fifa/fltOnlineAssets/8D941B48-51BB-4B87-960A-06A61A62EBC0/2015/fut/items/web/players.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will need

http://james.newtonking.com/json

```
public class Player
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int r { get; set; }
    public int n { get; set; }
    public string f { get; set; }
    public string l { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}

public class LegendsPlayer
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int r { get; set; }
    public int n { get; set; }
    public string f { get; set; }
    public string l { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public List<LegendsPlayer> LegendsPlayers { get; set; }
}


// Then you load int your comboBox

private void LoadComboItems()
    {
        var str = File.ReadAllText(pathToYourFile);
        var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str);
        foreach (var player in x.Players)
        {
            ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = player.f + " " + player.l;
            item.Value = player.id;

            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }        

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have only one issue, type ComboboxItem does not exist in my winform applicatlion. Do I missing something?

Comment: You need to import the control. I showed a way to make it easy

Comment: odd I think that ComboBox Item comes under System.Windows.Controls but I don't seem to have that in my normal windows form app.